# What is the best way of maintaining availability of my SQL database for Azure RemoteApp users?

Tags: sql, azure, remoteapp

My system has a number of users accessing a RemoteApp collection. The primary application they use is talking to an SQL database. Having a reliable connection to the database is critical in providing value to the users.

The SQL database resides on a Windows Server 2012 VM in Azure.

The VM is in an availability set with a VM taken from an image which is similar to my primary Windows Server VM. I understand that this will not protect my users from downtime caused by Microsoft?

Any guidance on overcoming this problem would be appreciated.

The two options I have thought of so far would be:

- Put my VM in an availability set with a constantly updated clone of
  itself (another instance of that machine?). I'm not sure this is
  possible or how I would implement it. Would I need to use Azure
  Powershell?
- Build an Azure SQL database and use that so the VM is not relied
  upon. Could do this through the portal or again through Azure
  Powershell.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question in some respect to be honest. Your first option would be using an Azure PaaS SQL deployment which will be maintained for availability.

Using an [availability set](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-manage-availability/) if correctly configured will protect you against the failure of the VM, however not the SQL application. You would then need to look at making SQL Server highly available in that instance as well as making the VM highly available.

One thing which is really important to note from the bottom of the link I sent is with a single instance VM in an availability set the SLA is not a guarantee.

> Avoid leaving a single instance virtual machine in an Availability Set by itself. Virtual machines in this configuration do not qualify for a SLA guarantee and will face downtime during Azure planned maintenance events. Please note, single virtual machine instance within an Availability Set, will also receive advanced email notification in multi-instance virtual machines planned maintenance notification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think rebuilding the database outside of the VM will be the simplest and most robust solution to the problem.

Comment: I agree, when working with cloud technology try and use everything at your disposal, designing the traditional way often leads to problems.